# UPS Shipping Extension Errors

Tags: ee2, expresso, ups-shipping

When attempting to use the UPS Shipping Extension for Exp-resso store, the install runs fine, but when attempting to add anything to the cart on the front-end we get the message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Store_ups_ext' does not have a method 'store_order_shipping_methods'
>
> Filename: libraries/Extensions.php
>
> Line Number: 262

I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall the UPS extension, the EE installation was newly installed prior to adding the UPS Extension.

We are using the following:

- EE 2.9.2
- Store 2.5.0
- UPS Extension 1.1.0

Thanks

Phil Dowson

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the UPS v1.1 installer. If you install this extension without updating from a previous one the installer uses the wrong method. You will need to run this query to get things working.

```
UPDATE exp_extensions SET method = 'shipping_methods' WHERE class = 'Store_ups_ext';
```